# Reading URLs from .csv and appending scrape results below previous with Python, BeautifulSoup, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

I got this code to almost work, despite much ignorance. Please help on the home run!

- Problem 1: INPUT:

I have a long list of URLs (1000+) to read from and they are in a single column in .csv. I would prefer to read from that file than to paste them into code, like below.

- Problem 2: OUTPUT:

The source files actually have 3 drivers and 3 challenges each. In a separate python file, the below code finds, prints and saves all 3, but not when I'm using this dataframe below (see below - it only saves 2).

- Problem 3: OUTPUT:

I want the output (both files) to have URLs in column 0, and then drivers (or challenges) in the following columns. But what I've written here (probably the 'drop') makes them not only drop one row but also move across 2 columns.

At the end I'm showing both the inputs and the current & desired output. Sorry for the long question. I'll be very grateful for any help!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

urls = ['https://www.marketresearch.com/Infiniti-Research-Limited-v2680/Global-Induction-Hobs-30196623/', 'https://www.marketresearch.com/Infiniti-Research-Limited-v2680/Global-Human-Capital-Management-30196628/', 'https://www.marketresearch.com/Infiniti-Research-Limited-v2680/Global-Probe-Card-30196643/']
dataframes = []
dataframes2 = []

for url in urls:
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    toc = soup.find("div", id="toc")

    def get_drivers():
        data = []
        for x in toc.select('li:-soup-contains-own("Market drivers") li'):
            data.append(x.get_text(strip=True))
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[url])
        dataframes.append(pd.DataFrame(df).drop(0, axis=0))
        df2 = pd.concat(dataframes)
        tdata = df2.T
        tdata.to_csv(f'detail-dr.csv', header=True)

    get_drivers()


    def get_challenges():
        data = []
        for y in toc.select('li:-soup-contains-own("Market challenges") li'):
            data.append(y.get_text(strip=True).replace('Table Impact of drivers and challenges', ''))
        df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=[url])
        dataframes2.append(pd.DataFrame(df).drop(0, axis=0))
        df2 = pd.concat(dataframes2)
        tdata = df2.T
        tdata.to_csv(f'detail-ch.csv', header=True)

    get_challenges()
```

**The inputs look like this in each URL. They are just lists:**

Market drivers

- Growing investment in fabs
- Miniaturization of electronic products
- Increasing demand for IoT devices

Market challenges

- Rapid technological changes in semiconductor industry
- Volatility in semiconductor industry
- Impact of technology chasm Table Impact of drivers and challenges

**My desired output for drivers is:**

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| http/.../Global-Induction-Hobs-30196623/ | Product innovations and new designs | Increasing demand for convenient home appliances with changes in lifestyle patterns | Growing adoption of energy-efficient appliances |
| http/.../Global-Human-Capital-Management-30196628/ | Demand for automated recruitment processes | Increasing demand for unified solutions for all HR functions | Increasing workforce diversity |
| http/.../Global-Probe-Card-30196643/ | Growing investment in fabs | Miniaturization of electronic products | Increasing demand for IoT devices |

**But instead I get:**

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| http/.../Global-Induction-Hobs-30196623/ | Increasing demand for convenient home appliances with changes in lifestyle patterns | Growing adoption of energy-efficient appliances |  |  |  |  |
| http/.../Global-Human-Capital-Management-30196628/ |  |  | Increasing demand for unified solutions for all HR functions | Increasing workforce diversity |  |  |
| http/.../Global-Probe-Card-30196643/ |  |  |  |  | Miniaturization of electronic products | Increasing demand for IoT devices |

Comment: Are there always only 3 drivers and 3 challenges (no more and no less) ?

Comment: No, in the examples above there are 3, but it may be anything from 0 to about 7

Comment: And how should they be handled? Should each driver have its own column such that if the same driver occurs for >= 2 different requests, they are mapped to the same column? Or does it not matter and you simply add another column each time a new driver is encountered?

Comment: Thanks @QHarr. Each row is independent of all other rows, so the columns just get filled with drivers from the left (after the url). If there is 0 drivers, then just the url on the left and no columns get filled. If there are 2 drivers, then the consecutive 2 columns get filled. If there are 7, then 7 columns get filled. Etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store your data in a list of dicts, create a data frame from it. Split the list of `drivers` / `challenges` into single `columns` and concat it to the final data frame.

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

urls = ['https://www.marketresearch.com/Infiniti-Research-Limited-v2680/Global-Induction-Hobs-30196623/', 'https://www.marketresearch.com/Infiniti-Research-Limited-v2680/Global-Human-Capital-Management-30196628/', 'https://www.marketresearch.com/Infiniti-Research-Limited-v2680/Global-Probe-Card-30196643/']
data = []

for url in urls:
    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
    toc = soup.find("div", id="toc")

    def get_drivers():
        data.append({
            'url':url,
            'type':'driver',
            'list':[x.get_text(strip=True) for x in toc.select('li:-soup-contains-own("Market drivers") li')]
        })

    get_drivers()


    def get_challenges():
        data.append({
            'url':url,
            'type':'challenges',
            'list':[x.text.replace('Table Impact of drivers and challenges','') for x in toc.select('li:-soup-contains-own("Market challenges") ul li') if x.text != 'Table Impact of drivers and challenges']
        })

    get_challenges()

    
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(data)[['url','type']], pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(data).list.tolist())],axis = 1)#.to_csv(sep='|')
```

#### Output

| url | type | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| https://www.marketresearch.com/Infiniti-Research-Limited-v2680/Global-Induction-Hobs-30196623/ | driver | Product innovations and new designs | Increasing demand for convenient home appliances with changes in lifestyle patterns | Growing adoption of energy-efficient appliances |
| https://www.marketresearch.com/Infiniti-Research-Limited-v2680/Global-Induction-Hobs-30196623/ | challenges | High cost limiting the adoption in the mass segment | Health hazards related to induction hobs | Limitation of using only flat - surface utensils and induction-specific cookware |
| https://www.marketresearch.com/Infiniti-Research-Limited-v2680/Global-Human-Capital-Management-30196628/ | driver | Demand for automated recruitment processes | Increasing demand for unified solutions for all HR functions | Increasing workforce diversity |
| https://www.marketresearch.com/Infiniti-Research-Limited-v2680/Global-Human-Capital-Management-30196628/ | challenges | Threat from open-source software | High implementation and maintenance cost | Threat to data security |
| https://www.marketresearch.com/Infiniti-Research-Limited-v2680/Global-Probe-Card-30196643/ | driver | Growing investment in fabs | Miniaturization of electronic products | Increasing demand for IoT devices |
| https://www.marketresearch.com/Infiniti-Research-Limited-v2680/Global-Probe-Card-30196643/ | challenges | Rapid technological changes in semiconductor industry | Volatility in semiconductor industry | Impact of technology chasm |

Comment: Nicely done there. Does this work for uneven numbers of columns? i.e. cases where different  numbers of drivers/challenges?

Comment: HedgeHog , thank you very much for this!!! Definitely solves the output issues. And I suppose having both driver sand challenges in one file rather than two, is just as good or perhaps even better. However, I still have that first question about reading the urls from a csv file. I think I know the basic structure of 'while open', but I'm having problems how to link that to the rest of the code. Your help (or @QHarr 's ) would be highly appreciated.

Comment: @QHarr: Thanks, in my opinion it also works with different lengths of drivers and challenges, it will be handled by the split and concat. Less columns become 'None'

Comment: @MichaelWiz: Happy to help - Concerning reding urls from csv, please ask a new question. Thanks

Comment: Thank you! Just posted it. In the meantime I have tested your code and it works perfectly. (I also tested for @QHarr 's example). Your code is so much more efficient than my messy attempt! Plus I think I understand 80% of what you've done here - the last 20% will take a while for me to study, though. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70139037/reading-list-of-urls-from-csv-for-scraping-with-python-beautifulsoup-pandas